# Upload photo and send it as a json object

Tags: c#, json, web-services, asp.net-mvc-4, http

I am using the view to upload a photo then I receive it in the controller as `HttpPostedFileBase`

then I send it in an Http request and things are just fine but when I recieve the http request in json object the photo comes as null`

here is the request:

```
 public ActionResult RegisterUsersCheck(User_all_data user_data)
        {
            var webAddr = "http://localhost:59305/api/User/RegisterUsersCheck";
            var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(webAddr);
            httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
            httpWebRequest.Accept = "application/json";
            httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";
            using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
            {
                string json = "{ user : { 'FirstName':'" + user_data.user.FirstName +
                    "','LastName': '" + user_data.user.LastName + "','Email': '" + user_data.user.Email +
                    "','Password': '" + user_data.user.Password + "','Country': '" + user_data.user.Country +
                    "','PhoneNumber': '" + user_data.ProfilePicture +
                    "'},'ProfilePicture': '" + user_data.PhoneNumber + "'}";
                streamWriter.Write(json);
                streamWriter.Flush();
            }

            var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
            using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
            {

                var result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
```

and here is how i receive the request

```
public bool RegisterUsersCheck ([FromBody] User_all_data user_ext)
        {
            List<User> all_users = repo.getUsers();
            var match = all_users.Find(i => i.Email == user_ext.user.Email);
            if (match == null)
            {
                RegisterUsers(user_ext);
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
```

and here is the `User_all_data` class

```
public class User_all_data
        {
            public User user { get; set; }
            public HttpPostedFileBase ProfilePicture { get; set; }
        }
```

as I mentioned earlier the sending is fine but when I receive the request the `ProfilePicture` is null

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, first of all, in this block of code

```
string json = "{ user : { 'FirstName':'" + user_data.user.FirstName +
                "','LastName': '" + user_data.user.LastName + "','Email': '" + user_data.user.Email +
                "','Password': '" + user_data.user.Password + "','Country': '" + user_data.user.Country +
                "','PhoneNumber': '" + user_data.ProfilePicture +
                "'},'ProfilePicture': '" + user_data.PhoneNumber + "'}";
```

It looks like the keys `PhoneNumber` and `ProfilePicture` are swapped.  You are setting the `PhoneNumber` to be the `ProfilePicture` and the `ProfilePicture` to be the `PhoneNumber`.  It should be the other way around.

Also, I'm not sure what data type `user_data.ProfilePicture` is, but if it's an image, you can't just stuff it into JSON.  JSON does not support binary data like an image.  One option is to base64 encode the image data before putting it into JSON.  Here's an example of doing this:

```
byte[] imageBytes = ...
var imageBytesStr = Convert.ToBase64String(imageBytes);
```

Then when you are constructing your JSON, set the `ProfilePicture` key to the base64 encoded string `imageBytesStr`.  Your clients then must base64 decode the `ProfilePicture` string to get the image bytes.  Then the clients must construct an image from these bytes.

Comment: This was helpful I just found away to get it into byte[] then use the conversion statement...Thanks